# Some sql queries working from PHP file but ORDER BY not

Tags: php, mysql

I’m relatively new to php and sql and currently trying to run queries from a php script on a table in phpmyadmin. I’m having an issue whereby some of my queries are working fine (hence it doesn’t feel like the DB connection is a problem), but the last query ($sql4 ORDER BY query) is not working. There is no error returned - it simply just doesn't order the data the way it should.

I don’t believe there is anything wrong with the sql code as I’ve tried running it in the SQL command window within phpmyadmin and it works fine there.  Code is below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost",$user, $pass);
if(!$con){
        die("Unable to connect msql". mysql_error());
        }
mysql_select_db("test_db_01", $con);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table_01 (unique_id, rates_1, rates_2,  rates_3, date)     VALUES ('$ID_val’,'$rate_val1’, '$rate_val2’,'$rate_val3’, now())";                                    
mysql_query($sql1, $con);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO table_02 (unique_id, score_tot_1, score_tot_2, score_tot_3) SELECT Unique_ID, Score_1*$rate_val1, Score_3*$rate_val3, Score_3*$rate_val3 FROM  ref_table";                                    
mysql_query($sql2, $con);

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO res_test_total_01 (Unique_ID, Total_Score) SELECT Unique_ID, score_tot_1 + score_tot_4 + score_tot_3 FROM table_02";                                    
mysql_query($sql3, $con);

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM res_test_total_01 ORDER BY Total_Score DESC";
mysql_query($sql4, $con);
```

Comment: What does the schema look like? What order are you expecting and what order are you getting? If it's returning rows at all I guarantee the `ORDER BY` is "working" (MySQL doesn't just take a day off when it feels like it), so the question is what you want it to be doing different from the way it normally works.

Comment: Does your `table_02` have a `Total_Score` column?

Comment: what do you mean "run queries from a php script on a table in phpmyadmin"?  You are pasting this query into PHPMyAdmin ?

Comment: Apologies - I entered this wrong.  The final query should read:

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM res_test_total_01 ORDER BY Total_Score DESC";
mysql_query($sql4, $con);

I want the records to be re-ordered by "Total_Score" from starting from highest in descending order.  However, when I check the table, it stays in the same order as it was prior to executing this query.

Comment: @CJOD 'check the table'? That does not make sense: 'Select...Order By' does not reorder the table, it orders the query-result...

Comment: @Tom Regner perhaps my approach is incorrect.  The reason I want to use ORDER BY is because ultimately I want to be able to retrieve the top 3 scoring records.  I thought I could ORDER BY and then after that store the first three records in the table to three variable as my top scoring results (as they would have been ordered by Total_Score).

Comment: @CJOD Yes of course 'ORBER BY xxx LIMIT 3', and the query result will be what you want - but this does not alter the table in any way -- you have to use the query result.

Comment: @Tom Regner thanks that makes sense.  I guess I thought the ORDER BY statement would alter the table but obviously it needs to be embedded within an INSERT INTO statement to do that.

Works now - thanks for clarifying! :)

Comment: @CJOD You're welcome; Glad I could help :)